# How to separate a collection on chunks with fixed number of items?

Tags: laravel

I have something like:

```php
$test = collect([
    123,
    234,
    345,
    456,
    // ...
]);
```

Which contains 1000 items. I would like to split into sub collections. I mean, I would like to see the following result:

```php
[
    [
    // 500 items here 
    ],
    [
    // and 500 items here
    ]
]
```

If I have 2000 items, then I would like to see:

```php
[
    [
    // 500 items here 
    ],
    [
    // and 500 items here
    ],
    [
    // 500 items here 
    ],
    [
    // and 500 items here
    ]
]
```

And so on. Which is the proper way to do this?

Comment: use array_chunk for this.

Comment: Model::select('column')
    ->get() ->chunk(500);

try this way if you getting record from databse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$collection = collect([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]);

$chunks = $collection->chunk(4);

$chunks->toArray();
```

This should output:

> [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
 $res = $test->chunk(500);
```

In view you can use a `foreach` loop to get the result